# on_member_update

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Пишу на disnake. Пытаюсь сделать ивент со сменой аватарки. Вот исходный код

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.avatar != after.avatar:
        channel = bot.get_channel(1116273214922952744)  
        await channel.send(f"{after.mention} сменил аватар на {after.avatar_url}")
```

Бот попросту не видит смену

Comment: У вас включены intents? Как сказано в официальной документации: `This requires Intents.members to be enabled.`

Comment: Да включены. Другой вопрос